# How to activate User after changing UID with usermod?

Tags: 11.10, users, login

Logged in as root and I changed the UID of user 'carmen' via terminal-command

```
usermod -u 502 carmen
```

but now user 'carmen' doesn't show up anymore on the login-screen (where you can choose, which account to log in), you can only log in via terminal. What happened?

Using Ubuntu 11.10 on a macbook.

Answer (score 4):

Any UID values below 1000 are treated as system type users.  These are hidden from the Login-screen.

If you want to see users on the Login-Screen the UID value needs to be greater than 1000.

Answer (score 2):

> You may also want to fix your login screen, since by default Ubuntu won't list users with a UID of less than 1000. To do this, just open a Terminal and run `gksudo gedit /etc/login.defs` and search for `UID_MIN` in the text file. Change that value from `1000` to `501`, and when you reboot your user will be listed in the login screen.

That information is from [this page](http://lifehacker.com/5702815/the-complete-guide-to-sharing-your-data-across-multiple-operating-systems).

If you don't want to wait for the reboot, you can just click "other" and manually enter the username and password info.

Comment: +1 Worked for me!  (Although I also got a user showing up named "vboxadd", where if you're running the VirtualBox guest additions it adds such a user at ID 999 by default.  Of course you can just move that out of the way, too...)